# Ask user to open or download file

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, download

I have a C# method that exports a database table and a JS function that starts a download. The JS is this:

```
function Export()
{
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("exportDatabaseTable", "MyController")',
        data:
        {
            'type': "xls" 
        },
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend: function () //Display a waiting message
        {
            $('#wait').show();
        },
        success: function (result) //Result is "Message|FilePath"
        {
            var res = result.split('|');
            if(res[0]!="Nothing found")
                window.location = "DownloadDatabaseTable?fileName=" + res[1];
            alert(res[0]);
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            alert("Export failed");
        },
        complete: function () //Hide the waiting message
        {
            $('#wait').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

While the C# one, called in the success function, is this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadDatabaseTable(string fileName)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
}
```

Everything works, but the download starts automatically. Is there a way to show the download windows and let the user choose to download (and where to download it) or to open the file?

Comment: Isn't that what browser should decide?

Comment: The action you want always handled by client's browser, even a JS handler can't be used to display dialog box for choosing view/save the returned file.